# Inspect element - how to get parameters sent to a redirected page and simulate it with postman?

Tags: redirect, postman, inspect-element

In this link there is a quiz when you click on Start Now:
https://www.clinique.com/diagnostics
After the quiz finished, it posts data to a link and immediately redirects to another page with quiz results. 
How to find out what data have been posted to the page and is there a way to simulate the final results with the Postman?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you're looking for is the [Postman Interceptor](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/capturing_http_requests) feature. It allows you to capture and inspect all the requests made from the browser/system you configure it to proxy to.

Then, once your request was captured, and after a bit of filtering (it'll capture every single request made to the server, not only the `POST` you're interested into) You will be able to replicate it with the Postman client like you'll do with a regular request. e.g. with the quiz you posted:

[image: postman interceptor capture flow]

**You'll find the data posted being sent as `x-www-form-urlencoded`** (what a mess!) on a `JSON` key with the value:

```
{
"ProfileName":"04-NA-USA ELC Online 4.05.2017",
"QuizVersion":6,
"QuizAnswers":[
    {
        "attributeName":"welcome",
        "attributeRecapValuesLocalized":"mens_concerns",
        "recapColumn":1
    },
    {
        "attributeName":"mens_concerns",
        "attributeRecapValuesLocalized":"Eye Area",
        "recapColumn":0
    },
    {
        "attributeName":"mens_age",
        "attributeRecapValuesLocalized":"50 - 59",
        "recapColumn":1
    },
    {
        "attributeName":"mens_eye_area_where",
        "attributeRecapValuesLocalized":"Lines/Wrinkles",
        "recapColumn":0
    },
    {
        "attributeName":"mens_skintype",
        "attributeRecapValuesLocalized":"oily-shiny,tight-uncomfortable",
        "recapColumn":0
    },
    {
        "attributeName":"mens_sensitivity_frequency",
        "attributeRecapValuesLocalized":"Rarely",
        "recapColumn":1
    },
    {
        "attributeName":"mens_sensitivity_redness",
        "attributeRecapValuesLocalized":"No",
        "recapColumn":1
    },
    {
        "attributeName":"recap",
        "attributeRecapValuesLocalized":"",
        "recapColumn":1
    }
],
"SkinType":"2",
"SKUs":[
    {
        "Eye Area":[
            "7YXH-01",
            "7ELF-01",
            "6TCR-01"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Daily Care":[
            "ZE4L-01",
            "ZF7E-01",
            "65EM-01",
            "Z219-01",
            "Z5WW-01"
        ]
    }
],
"UPCs":[
    {
        "Eye Area":[
            "020714632670",
            "020714506827",
            "020714382742"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Daily Care":[
            "020714734510",
            "020714744762",
            "020714104726",
            "020714649562",
            "020714682255"
        ]
    }
],
"Concerns#1":"Eye Area",
"Concerns#2":"Daily Care",
"UsageOrderSKUs":[
    "ZE4L-01",
    "ZF7E-01",
    "65EM-01",
    "7YXH-01",
    "Z219-01",
    "Z5WW-01",
    "7ELF-01",
    "6TCR-01"
],
"UsageOrderUPCs":[
    "020714734510",
    "020714744762",
    "020714104726",
    "020714632670",
    "020714649562",
    "020714682255",
    "020714506827",
    "020714382742"
]
}
```